# How to compare one set of columns with another set of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

Consider that we have the below data

```r
df <- data.frame(jan=c(10,7,1),
           feb=c(20,9,2),
           mar=c(30,6,3),
           apr=c(5,5,4),
           may=c(0,9,5),
           jun=c(10,8,6)
)


  jan feb mar apr may jun
1  10  20  30   5   0  10
2   7   9   6   5   9   8
3   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

I am expecting to derive a new flag variable which is derived by comparing the 1 set of columns (jan feb mar) with (apr may jun), if the values of 1 set match the values of another set then flag='Y', else 'N'.

Here jan value match jun for the first row so the flag is Y.

```r
  jan feb mar apr may jun flag
1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

Comment: Is this a row-by-row comparison? Is (jan feb mar) in each row compared with (apr may jun) in the same row or (apr may jun) across the whole table?

Comment: its a row by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we iterate through the rows of the dataframe and `unlist` the dataframe into vectors per "set" in each iteration. Then use the `%in%` operator to see if `any` element in the first set appears in the second set. Finally assign the result to the `flag` column of `df`.

The `ifelse` part is just for converting logical output to "Y" and "N". You can ignore it if you're fine with logical output.

```r
df$flag <- sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) 
                  ifelse(any(unlist(df[x, 1:3]) %in% unlist(df[x, 4:6])), "Y", "N"))
df
#>   jan feb mar apr may jun flag
#> 1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
#> 2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
#> 3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

Answer (score 2):

A vectorized approach if performance is a concern:

```
set1 <- c("jan", "feb", "mar")
set2 <- c("apr", "may", "jun")

iY <- unique(
  data.table(
    r = rep(1:nrow(df), each = ncol(df)),
    val = c(unlist(t(df[c(set1, set2)]))),
    set = rep(1:2, c(length(set1), length(set2))),
    key = c("r", "val")
  )[r == shift(r) & val == shift(val) & set != shift(set), r]
)
df$flag <- "N"
df$flag[iY] <- "Y"
df
#>   jan feb mar apr may jun flag
#> 1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
#> 2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
#> 3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

Benchmarking against a couple of the other solutions on a larger dataset. First implement the solutions as functions.

```
df <- setNames(
  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(10, 6e4, 1), 1e4, 6)),
  c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun")
)

f1 <- function(df, set1, set2) {
  df$flag <- sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) 
                    ifelse(any(unlist(df[x, set1]) %in% unlist(df[x, set2])), "Y", "N"))
  df
}

f2 <- function(df, set1, set2) {
  iY <- unique(
    data.table(
      r = rep(1:nrow(df), each = ncol(df)),
      val = c(unlist(t(df[c(set1, set2)]))),
      set = rep(1:2, c(length(set1), length(set2))),
      key = c("r", "val")
    )[r == shift(r) & val == shift(val) & set != shift(set), r]
  )
  df$flag <- "N"
  df$flag[iY] <- "Y"
  df
}

f3 <- function(df, set1, set2) {
  df$flag <- c("N", "Y")[(lengths(
    Map(
      intersect,
      asplit(df[set1], 1),
      asplit(df[set2], 1)
    )
  ) > 0) + 1]
  df
}
```

Benchmark

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(df, set1, set2),
  f2 = f2(df, set1, set2),
  f3 = f3(df, set1, set2),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval
#>    f1 733.1518 778.70590 927.068694 848.8564 999.61955 1687.4810   100
#>    f2   4.9241   5.64215   6.283577   6.3074   6.82695    9.2447   100
#>    f3 119.9982 134.07060 165.306384 151.6871 189.23330  282.1914   100
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
df$flag <- c("N", "Y")[(lengths(
    Map(
        intersect,
        asplit(df[1:3], 1),
        asplit(df[-(1:3)], 1)
    )
) > 0) + 1]
```

which should give

```
> df
  jan feb mar apr may jun flag
1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) dplyr** On each row if any of the first 3 columns is in any of the next 3 columns then set flag to Y and otherwise to N.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(flag = if (any(pick(1:3) %in% pick(4:6))) "Y" else "N") %>%
  ungroup

## # A tibble: 3 × 7
##     jan   feb   mar   apr   may   jun flag 
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
## 1    10    20    30     5     0    10 Y    
## 2     7     9     6     5     9     8 Y    
## 3     1     2     3     4     5     6 N
```

**2) Base R**

```
df |>
  by(1:nrow(df), transform, flag =
    if (any(c(jan, feb, mar) %in% c(apr, may, jun))) "Y" else "N") |>
  do.call(what = "rbind")

##   jan feb mar apr may jun flag
## 1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
## 2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
## 3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

**3) collapse**

```
library(collapse)

yn <- function(x) if (any(x[1:3] %in% x[4:6])) "Y" else "N"
tfm(df, flag = dapply(df, yn, MARGIN = 1))

##   jan feb mar apr may jun flag
## 1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
## 2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
## 3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

**4) Base R - 2** This uses the `yn` function from (3).

```
transform(df, flag = apply(df, 1, yn))

##   jan feb mar apr may jun flag
## 1  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
## 2   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
## 3   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

### Note

The input `df` from the question:

```
df <- data.frame(
  jan = c(10, 7, 1),
  feb = c(20, 9, 2),
  mar = c(30, 6, 3),
  apr = c(5, 5, 4),
  may = c(0, 9, 5),
  jun = c(10, 8, 6)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to flag rows in which any of {jan, feb, mar} match any value in {apr, may, jun}.  With the data.table package, you can select lines matching your search pattern and then assign a new flag column with "Y"

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(df)

DT[jan %in% c(apr, may, jun) | feb %in% c(apr, may, jun) | mar %in% c(apr, may, jun), flag:="Y"]
DT[is.na(flag), flag:="N"]      # if you want N for ones that don't fit your pattern

   jan feb mar apr may jun flag
1:  10  20  30   5   0  10    Y
2:   7   9   6   5   9   8    Y
3:   1   2   3   4   5   6    N
```

This approach lets you specify columns by names, so it's less likely to break if the order of columns is ever changed.

Comment: This won't do a row-by-row comparison. The (jan feb mar) in each row is compared with (apr may jun) across the whole table.